# calling delete rest api by jquery

Tags: ajax, api, rest, jquery

I had called the GET REST API by following code :

```
 $.getJSON('http://myapisite.com/user/1?callback=?', function(msg){
         console.log(msg);
      });
```

But for calling  DELETE REST API through jquery 
what i had tried is :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mysite.com/user/1?callback=?',
  type: 'DELETE',
      dataType: 'json',
         data: '',
  success: function(response) { console.log('PUT completed'+response); }
      });.
```

and this api is not being called , I want to know how should i call the DELETE REST API .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do a cross-domain request.  This means that you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` (the basis of AJAX) because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  You are using a workaround called JSONP, which works by inserting `<script>` tags into your document.

Script tags will **always** fetch content via GET, so you can't do a DELETE, POST, PUT or suchlike with them.

The best workaround would be to have a script on your own server that proxies the DELETE request for you.

Comment: FWIW, most REST APIs provide some way of using the DELETE and PUT methods using only GET and POST, since browsers' support for the DELETE and PUT methods are somewhat limited. Usually this means appending a query string (GET variables) to the url.

Comment: @all m using Zend Framework for API script. so How i can append in GET variable ?

Comment: @Rahul **Are** you trying to do a cross-domain request?

Comment: Yeah because the Zend Framework need to give different Domain For API Call. I think I may be wrong .

Comment: It is running on Sub-Domain .

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see any evidence that the OP is facing a cross-domain issue.  He's simply asking why jQuery's AJAX code is not supporting his `DELETE` command.  I have exactly the same question.  Can my jQuery front end fire off a `DELETE` request to '/mystuff/1' to trigger my API's delete command or do I have to fudge it with a `POST`?

Comment: @DaveSag It's obvious he's doing a JSONP request because of the `callback=?` part of the URL. You really need to ask a new question for your problem.

Comment: In my case the standard `POST` fudge with `_method='delete'` worked a treat.